# Java Synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

Is it valid to update a reference in an synchronized block of that reference?
eg:

```
Synchronized(list)
{
  list = new ArrayList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is completely valid but what would you achieve by doing this? Besides, **threads gain lock on object instance not on variable which holds object reference** so even if you reassign `list` with some other instance, current thread has already taken lock on the previous object.

To clarify more, let's say `list` was assigned value `val1`. Then a `thread1` takes lock on `val1` (which is pointed by variable `list`), now other threads can't take lock on `val1` (because they are waiting for lock on instance `val1` not on reference `list`) even though `thread1` has re-instantiated `list`.

Better would be to clear the `list` inside `synchronized` block instead of re-initializing it.

Comment: I want to update this list by another list. It would be better to clear this list and add all instead?  There are other threads iterating on this list.

Comment: @AkashMahajan Yes, ideally that should be the approach.

Answer (score 5):

When you write

```
synchronized (list)
```

The lock is an *object*, not the variable/field `list`.

If you do

```
synchronized (list) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

you are creating a new object, and reassigning a variable/field - but you have not changed the lock - the lock is still the same object it was before.